# Incest in Freezing

Tags: freezing

In Freezing, Gengo Aoi tries to build a relationship between two characters, but this relationship would be incestuous. Did any one of these characters consider the nature of this relationship?

I ask this, because in no argument is incest mentioned.

The characters that should be shipped are:

> Ryuuichi Aoi, Gengo's son with Maria

and

> Cassandra, an incomplete clone of Maria.

Comment: at least she is incomplete :v

Comment: at least she is incomplete :v

Comment: @NamikazeSheena but her dna is still mostly that of his mother...